# Javascript beforeunload event not working with iframe

Tags: javascript, iframe

in the following code for binding unload & beforeunload to iframe. The later one is not working.

```
myIframe.contentWindow.addEventListener('unload', function() { 
    alert("Page is reloaded");
});
myIframe.contentWindow.addEventListener("beforeunload", function(event) {
    event.returnValue = "Redirection triggered";
});
```

Thanks,
Titus

Comment: What have tried to fix the event triggering?

Comment: Does specifying the full event name `onbeforeunload` help?

Comment: it didn't @Dumisani. But onbeforeunload is used in jquery right for javascript it says https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onbeforeunload.asp beforeunload